# PHP PDO - Fetchall doesn't print out value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to select a simple data from my database:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT new_email FROM pending_emails WHERE userid=:userid AND type='email'");
$stmt->bindParam(":userid",$userdata["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
     $emailUpdateData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($emailUpdateData) == 1){

                $emailUpdate = true;

     }
```

I then try to use the `$emailUpdateData` like this:

```
  echo $emailUpdateData["new_email"];
```

But that doesn't return anything.

If I do a `print_r` I get this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [new_email] => support@hotmail.com ) )
```

Comment: So where do you try to echo that out?In the same page?Then remove the php tags.

Comment: @Mihai That's not the reason... the tags was used further down in between HTMl.

Comment: $emailUpdateData is array of arrays : `echo $emailUpdateData[0]["new_email"];`

Comment: Don't use `echo $emailUpdateData[0]["new_email"];` - fix your query instead to return one row.

Comment: Another way... `$theEmail = current($emailUpdateData);  echo $theEmail['new_email'];` should do what you want. see: [current — Return the current element in an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php). Doesn't care what the index is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetchall return always an array of rows as a recordset. Imagine that your select return a list of values, you will need and array to store all of them, with their key->value in each of them.

So, fetchall will you return always an array, even when the resultset has only one result or you limit it in SQL sentence with a LIMIT clause.

In this case, you need to access to the array as

```
$emailUpdateData[0]["new_email"]
```

If you want only to get the first row, replace fetchAll to fetch

Answer (score 0):

`fetchAll()` returns an array of rows; use `fetch()` to return one row.

You should also add `LIMIT 1` to your query for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$emailUpdateData = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to

```
$emailUpdateData = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

fetch() returns 1 row, fetchAll() returns all rows.

Comment: Changing it to fetch() doesn't change anything. It still doesn't return anything.